# How to add vertical spacing between flexbox wrapped items in bootstrap4?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

In bootstrap 4 I have the following code:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row no-gutter">
        <div class="d-none d-md-flex col-md-12 flex-wrap">      
    <div style="width:100px;height:50px;float:left;display:block;background:red;">Div</div>
    <div style="width:100px;height:50px;float:left;display:block;background:red;">Div</div>
    <div style="width:100px;height:50px;float:left;display:block;background:red;">Div</div>
    <div style="width:100px;height:50px;float:left;display:block;background:red;">Div</div>
    <div style="width:100px;height:50px;float:left;display:block;background:red;">Div</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Issue I have is as soon as there is a 'wrapped item', it appears to get stuck to the bottom of the items above. When I try to apply a margin-bottom:5px to each of the divs, it appears to have no effect. What is the correct way to handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things in your code...

- why use float with flex? Bootstrap 4 uses flex instead of float (which was used by bootstrap 3)
- the divs in pink are from your code with classes removed to show the effect in the browser/snippet
- the divs in blue show the solution with flex (using bootstrap 4 classes)
- margin-bottom works in both

**working snippet** below:

```css
.flex-wrap>div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  display: block;
}

.my-divs {
  float: left;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  background: lightpink;
}

.my-flex-div {
  background: lightblue;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">


<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row no-gutter">
    <div class=" d-md-flex col-md-12 flex-wrap">
      <div class="my-divs">Div</div>
      <div class="my-divs">Div</div>
      <div class="my-divs">Div</div>
      <div class="my-divs">Div</div>
      <div class="my-divs">Div</div>
    </div>
    <hr/>
    <div class="d-flex flex-wrap">
      <div class="my-flex-div">Div 2</div>
      <div class="my-flex-div">Div 2</div>
      <div class="my-flex-div">Div 2</div>
      <div class="my-flex-div">Div 2</div>
      <div class="my-flex-div">Div 2</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is most likely your use of `float` that is causing the problem. However this whole layout can be achieved using only Bootstrap default classes and no additional CSS.

First, there is no need for a row/col layout if you are only using a `col-12` full-width single column. Simply remove the `row no-gutter` and `col-12` classes.

Second, BS4 includes utility classes for margin. [Read about them here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/utilities/spacing/).

Try the example below. I have used multiple background colors for clarity.

```
.flex-wrap div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="d-flex flex-wrap">
    <div class="mb-5 bg-primary">Div</div>
    <div class="mb-5 bg-secondary">Div</div>
    <div class="mb-5 bg-warning">Div</div>
    <div class="mb-5 bg-success">Div</div>
    <div class="mb-5 bg-danger">Div</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Here is a working codepen example.](https://codepen.io/arajay/pen/vYEexzr)